# "Too many indices for array" Error in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

All of the below values are integers/floats.

```
# atomic density of Pu
MPu = 239.0
NPu = np.array(((p*avo)/(MPu))*cm2tobarns)

# atomic density of U
MU = 238.07
NU = np.array(((p*avo)/(MU))*cm2tobarns)
```

Here are the matrices/arrays being called

```
Ugroup = np.array([[1.28, 0.78, 0.2, 0.03, 0.003, 0, 0],
       [0, 1.05, 0.42, 0.01, 0.01, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0.33, 0.04, 0.005, 0.0009, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0.29, 0.003, 0.0005, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.18, 0.02, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.09, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01]])

Pugroup = np.array([[0.66, 0.6, 0.19, 0.04, 0.005, 0, 0],
       [0, 0.64, 0.15, 0.03, 0.006, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0.31, 0.05, 0.01, 0.0009, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0.18, 0.01, 0.0005, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.13, 0.02, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.09, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01]])
```

Here is a portion of what I am trying to do.I keep getting an error message for the first line.

```
Sig12 = (Pugroup[0,0]*NPu) + (Ugroup[0,0]*NU)
Sig13 = (Pugroup[0,1]*NPu) + (Ugroup[0,1]*NU)
Sig14 = (Pugroup[0,2]*NPu) + (Ugroup[0,2]*NU)
Sig15 = (Pugroup[0,3]*NPu) + (Ugroup[0,3]*NU)
Sig16 = (Pugroup[0,4]*NPu) + (Ugroup[0,4]*NU)
Sig17 = (Pugroup[0,5]*NPu) + (Ugroup[0,5]*NU)
Sig18 = (Pugroup[0,6]*NPu) + (Ugroup[0,6]*NU)
```

Above is my code, I am trying to multiply specific values by a constant and then add them together for further calculations. However, I keep getting this error. I have tried making the constants an array, but that doesn't work. I am not sure what does.

Comment: Please make an running example of the problem that we can use for test and to modify in a solution. Include the traceback of the failure in the example.

Comment: In `Ugroup` for example, you have different sized lists (some 7, some 8) and no declared data type, so numpy is creating a 1 dimensional array of python lists. In that case you need to do `Ugroup[0][1]` where the first indexes the numpy array and the second indexes the python list. Where they all 7 value lists, numpy would make a 2 dimensional array and `0,1` would work. Please make a working example so that we can figure out if this is the issue and post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need not to index with commas but with `[0][0]` et cetera

Comment: Will you give a more specific example to clarify your answer?

Comment: when he calls the various group elements, he needs to use double squared parenthesis cause it s a nested array

Comment: Commas work for an n-dimensional numpy array. I think the problem here is that OP has a 1 dimensional array of python lists.

Comment: @jahnLudvik Please [edit] your question to show a full example, include the variable name with the bracket notation.